# how to Capture database insert row event into a web application built using Spring web mvc?

Tags: database, spring, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0

I have a requirement where in I need to capture an insert row event in to the table in a web application to notify to the user about what latest record has been added.

**Scenario**

An application **A1** keeps pumping records to a database **D1**. A web application **W1** should be notified with any new record inserted to the database **D1**.

The web application is developed using spring-web-mvc, JPA persistence. I looked at option of using entitylistner events provided by jpa and hibernate but this limits if the the same application performs the insert operation, which is not the case.

Could you someone please help me , how could I resolve this ?

Comment: Which database? Say Postgres

Comment: In my case its MySql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your requirements there are many ways to achieve what you want.

Since you did not provide specific requirements let me just throw a few ideas on how it could be achieved.

**1. Using Database Triggers**: you could add a trigger to the table in question. When D1 inserts a record into this table, using an insert trigger you can add the ID of the record to a notification table. Your application W1 could have an scheduled task reading records from the notification table. Let's say it runs every 5 seconds and checks if there are new records there. If so, it reads them, process them,
and then deletes the record from the notification table.

**2. Using Queues**: if records can only be inserted into the table in question through the application D1, and so application D1 is the only entry point for records in this table, then you use a message queue. When a new record is inserted by D1, you send a message with the inserted record details to a message queue. Application W1 is just a subscriber of this queue. Once records arrive, W1 reads them from the queue and process them.

**3. Using a Web Service:** once more if records can only be inserte through D1, then W1 could expose a web service to be notified when records are created. As such when D1 creates a new record, it could also invoke this web service and let W1 know that a new record was just inserted, than W1 can act accordingly.

And there are probably many more alternatives ways to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer, it is helpful. In my research, I had come across  database triggers.  Do you have any idea, can the trigger directly call the web application?,  I heard about triggers calling a java program. With this approach, it would avoid writing a scheduler at the server end.

Comment: @pavan I would consider a trigger talking directly to a web application a really bad idea. With Spring [setting up a schedule task](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support) is probably much simpler.

Comment: I agree with you, but still curious to know is it really possible for talking directly with the web application from a trigger?